# AngularJS Using multiple instances of one controller

Tags: angularjs, controller

I'm trying to use a single controller for two parts of a large form. I've successfully done this with one controller, but another refuses to work in both parts.

To explain how I did this. I created two directives which pull in separate templates for vehicle information. Make, model, body type and so on. The custom tags are as follows:

```
<my-sale-vehicle-form ng-controller="vehicleFormCtrl as sale_vform"></my-sale-vehicle-form>
<my-trade-vehicle-form ng-controller="vehicleFormCtrl as trade_vform"></my-trade-vehicle-form>
```

As you can see each uses the vehicleFormCtrl controller as an alias allowing me to display data from each alias and load data from the controller into the form fields.

Now I figured if this will work I should be able to display multiple instances of a custom warranty form using the same technique as seen below. I attempted it, but I can't seem to get it to work in the same way. I've checked over the templates and each refers to the right alias. Usually what happens is that one will work, or neither will work. If I remove the second instance the first will work. I just can't wrap my brain around why this works in one situation and not the other. I do not get any errors in the console either. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

```
<my_pack0-warranty-form ng-controller="customWarrantyFormCtrl as custwarforma"></my_pack0-warranty-form>
<my_pack1-warranty-form ng-controller="customWarrantyFormCtrl as custwarformb"></my_pack1-warranty-form>
```

Comment: Sorry my thoughts weren't entirely clear when I posted this. The data will actually show up in the second or last instance of customWarrantyFormCtrl every time. This is not intermittent. I had noticed similar behavior when I didn't give the vehicle form controllers alias'.

Comment: what do you mean with "but another refuses to work in both parts."?

Comment: I mean that the vehicle controller works in two areas of the form while the custom warranty controller does not. As seen above in the code they are both instantiated twice. The warranty controller only seems to bind to the last element.

Comment: I don't know if this would have any effect or not but they are both embedded in other controllers, which are for packages. The warranty information must be bound to the package as well.

Comment: Is using same controller a bad practice?